# Difference between $\phi$ anf $\epsilon$ in regular language.

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

What is the interpretation of both $\emptyset$ and $\epsilon$ in a regular language?

Do they both mean empty sets?

If so then why is

$\emptyset^*=\epsilon$ , $\emptyset^+=\emptyset$

and 
$\epsilon^*=\epsilon$,  $\epsilon^+=\epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are not actually same kind of items.

$\epsilon$ is a **word** while $\emptyset$ is a **set** of words (a.k.a. a *language*).

$\{\epsilon\}$ is the language containing only the empty word (i.e. $|\{\epsilon\}|=1$ and it is different from $\emptyset$ which doesn't contain any word ($|\emptyset|=0$).

For a language $L$, $L^*$ stands for the concatenation of 0 or more words from $L$, therefore $$\emptyset^*=\{\epsilon\}$$

$L^+$ on the other hand is the concatenation of 1 or more words from $L$. Since there are no words in $\emptyset$, $\emptyset^+=\emptyset$, while for $\{\epsilon\}$ you could pick the empty word $\{\epsilon\}$ and thus $\{\epsilon\}^+=\{\epsilon\}$.

Comment: If $\phi$ is an empty set then how can $\phi*$ can contain a word $\epsilon$?? it's like 0Xn=0 right?

Comment: @gman - Because $L^*$, for any language $L$ is defined as concatenation of $0$ or more words from $L$. Even in the empty language you could take a concatenation of 0 words, which is, by definition $\epsilon$.

Comment: @gman - This all comes from the fact that concatenation of 0 words is **defined** to be $\epsilon$.

Comment: Shouldn't {ϵ}+ = ϵ ? @RB

Comment: @PalakJain - No. $\{\epsilon\}^+$ is the set of all words that are generated from a finite concatenation of $\epsilon$s. This is a language that contains one word - $\epsilon$.